# Specify modified error function in form of error functions

Tags: integration, special-functions

How can we express $\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t-a}{m})$ as a sum of functions of the form $\mathrm{erf}(t)$?

I am developing a fitting routine and I encounter this integral:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{t-a}{m}\right) \cdot t \cdot J_{0}(qt)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
I have an analytic solution for the following form:
$$ \int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{erf}(t)\cdot t \cdot J_{0}(qt) \,\mathrm{d}t$$

So I am looking to transform the original integral into something like this, and I can try to handle any extra variables ($t$) that may emerge during this transformation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to express $erf((t-a)/m)$ as an R-linear combination of functions of the form $t^b erf(ct)$?

Comment: @MattF. Yes, Exactly that's what I want.